# Could not translate expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
from p in context.ParentCompanies
where p.Name.Contains(e.Filter)
orderby p.Name
select new { Company = p.Name + "," + p.Country  };
```

The above `linq` query fails when I add *p.Country* or any other attribute.

Exception:

*`Could not translate expression 'Table(ParentCompany).Where(p =>
p.Name.Contains(Invoke(value(System.Func'1[System.String])))).OrderBy(p
=> p.Name)' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression`.*

Comment: What exception says when you remove "where" clause from your query?

Comment: The same exception occurs.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to SQL in not able to translate your string manipulation to SQL. Select both p.Name and p.Country from your database and then concatenate in a separated step, like this:

```
var parentCompanies = (from p in context.ParentCompanies
                       where p.Name.Contains(e.Filter)
                       orderby p.Name
                       select new { p.Name, p.Country }).ToList();

var concatenated = (from c in parentCompanies
                    select new { Company = c.Name + "," + c.Country });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `class` and inherit the `ParentCompanies`

```
public ParentCompaniesEntity : ParentCompanies
{
   public string CompanyCountry {get; set;}
}
```

and this is how to use.

```
var parentCompanies = (from p in context.ParentCompanies
                       where p.Name.Contains(e.Filter)
                       orderby p.Name
                       select new ParentCompaniesEntity() 
                       { 
                         CompanyCountry = p.Name + ", " + p.Country
                       }).ToList();
```